# Can't print in black with Epson Stylus BX525DW

Tags: printing

I have installed an ethernet connected Epson Stylus BX525DW printer. I can print in colours and I can scan documents. Installation was automatic. It took me 10 seconds. However I can't print in black.

Note that the inks are not the original. I bought inks from ebay. However, the same printer was printing in black in windows before. Although black is almost grey (inks are of terrible quality, that is a fact).

These are my CUPS settings:

```
<Printer Epson-Stylus-Office-BX525WD>
UUID urn:uuid:3d09dd67-c833-36e8-4cd7-a5b90c67b7da
Info EPSON Epson Stylus Office BX525WD
MakeModel Epson Stylus Office BX535WD - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9
DeviceURI lpd://192.168.1.4:515/PASSTHRU
State Idle
StateTime 1393924901
Type 8425484
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
Attribute marker-colors \#000000,#FF00FF,#FFFF00,#00FFFF
Attribute marker-levels 100,100,100,100
Attribute marker-names Black Ink Cartridge,Magenta Ink Cartridge,Yellow Ink Cartridge,Cyan Ink Cartridge
Attribute marker-types inkCartridge,inkCartridge,inkCartridge,inkCartridge
Attribute marker-change-time 1393924901
</Printer>
```

Can I fix this?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: How were you able to print those settings out? Sorry, I must be very bad with google because I've been searching and haven't found any instructions for how to get this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I connected to CUPS (localhost:631) and set on the Default Printer Options to use CMYK and not RGB (which was the initial default value). That makes sense because my printer uses four inks.

That should have been the selected value from the start. I haven't used a printer which uses RGB colous instead of CMYK.

Comment: Where is this option? I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with cups 2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4.1; I've been scouring the web interface but can't find anything matching "Default Printer Options", much less CMYK vs RGB defaults?

Comment: This is a very old question. Most probably things must have changed in some way...

Comment: I think... what's actually happening is that this option is only exposed on some printer drivers. Ongoing hardware churn means that current (2022) drivers are worse and have fewer features than the drivers for similar printer hardware from 10-20 years go. That said, it's the really the responsibility of the printer manufacturers to prepare these drivers to expose a printer's full functionality. Which, as we all know, means it doesn't happen  :/