# Can not print black text

Tags: 16.04, printing

I can print onloy in colors, but printing black text is almost invisible.

Here is what I have (ask more info if necessary) from  `http://127.0.0.1:631/` :

```
Description:    HP Photosmart C5100 series
Location:   begueradj-bill
Driver: HP Photosmart c5100 Series, hpcups 3.16.3 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: hp:/usb/Photosmart_C5100_series?serial=MY79QQ63KP04MK
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=one-sided
```

I read this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429694/cant-print-in-black-with-epson-stylus-bx525dw/431247#431247) but I do not see the options the OP mentioned as my screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to replace the black cartridge? BTW, whatever you were trying to show, it doesn't work if you post local links.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. All the catridges are new. The link I provided is just [CUPS web interface](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems#CUPS_web_interface)

Comment: Yes, I know what it is. The point is no-one else can see it and is pretty much irrelevant anyway. The troubleshooting you should be doing is printing from another computer and/or other OS. This is to rule out an hardware issue obviously. At first glance this has nothing to do with Ubuntu - printer works and the driver is correct.

Comment: I was used to print with this same machine and OS both in black and colors, but around 4 months ago I can print only in colors. I have no clue why.